# How to share text or custom url to facebook using uiactivityviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I actually want to share a custom url which does not start with 'https/http' but , 'puzzle://', where 'puzzle' is my URL Scheme. So I am sharing it as String instead of url. I am able to share that link/text via Twitter & Email using uiactivityviewcontroller.  But somehow, facebook dialog box shows nothing. Also tell me that if I should share it as text or link. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Facebook validates the URL shared to be a valid URL not any fake string in URL , a valid URL will be loaded in the sharing box otherwise it's not valid .

Example of a valid URL :

```
http://Google.com
```

Good luck!